# Recover sha1 password for transferring SMF members to WP users?

Tags: sha1

is it possible to recover a sha1 password (SMF part)?

I need this to convert SMF members to WP users. I am able to import/convert all the info per SMF member, only the password part isn't going well.

In smf_members table i also see a passwordSalt column, do i need this to convert the password.

At the moment i am testing with passwordpro for just one password but i can't seem to get it going and waiting 1 day seems a bit long? What i am doing wrong with this program??

Regards

SMF = Simple Machine Forum
WP = WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found a bit of a workaround to get SMF members to WP users by 
- installing buddypress
- buddypress smf import plugin
- take a close look at the smf_password_compatibility plugin`which converts the SMF password to WP password
    $check = ( $hash == sha1( strtolower( $user_info->user_login ) . $password) );
    if ( $check && $user_id ) {
        // Rehash using new hash.
        wp_set_password($password, $user_id);
        $hash = wp_hash_password($password);
        return true;
    }`